# Naive Read-Write Lock

Tags: concurrency, deadlocks

Consider the simply read-write lock algorithm that allows many readers and a single writer. Why is this algorithm flawed?

I was thinking about the implementation of a well-known read-write lock library and wondering why it didn't do this simpler approach.

**To read:**

1. atomically add 1.
2. if the old value was less than N, proceed. When you're done, subtract 1.
3. otherwise, subtract 1, wait, and try again.

**To write:**

Pick a fixed large number N, greater than the number of readers will every be (it can be in the billions).

1. atomically add a N.
2. if the old value was zero, proceed. When you're done, subtract N.
3. otherwise, subtract N, wait, and try again.

Comment: This can starve the writer. Think of MANY readers and only one writer.

Answer (score 0):

It will work but generally we cant take the assumption that N is known beforehand.